# How to render a segmented volume?

Tags: rendering, color

[Here](http://www.spl.harvard.edu/publications/item/view/1918) is a segmented volume with 96 different features. I wish to visualize each feature with a distinct color. I followed [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/example/UseACustomColorFunction.html) documentation and used `Blend` to assign colors to the features. However, when I check each individual feature, I find that in some cases the feature is assigned with one color while the rendered output shows a different color.

I think the use of `Blend` is the problem here.

The alternative that I can think of is to first apply `ClusteringComponents` using `KMeans` and then use `Colorize`. However, using `ClusteringComponents` on a segmented data is a redundant process and it takes a long time and moreover, there is no guarantee that it will return all the segmented (initial) parts.

How can I render this volume properly so that each segment gets rendered with the same color that is assigned to that segment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download the `zip` that contains the `.vtk` files and extract it. Then, find all these files in Mathematica

```
vtks = FileNames["*.vtk", {"/path/to/AbdominalAtlas2011/"}]
```

After that, use `Import[file, "Elements"]` to see what Mathematica can extract from `vtk` files. Use whatever you like, but I guess something like this should help you

```
mkGraphics[file_String] := {RandomColor[], EdgeForm[None], 
   Import[file, "GraphicsComplex"]};

Graphics3D[
 mkGraphics /@ Select[vtks, Not[StringFreeQ[#, "Rib"]] &],
 BoxRatios -> Automatic
 ]
```

Et voilà

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Bringing in the original colors

The colors are stored in a separate file as far as I can see, but it's a simple format and you can turn it into an association that maps the model-id to its color:

```
colors = Association @@ Apply[
    #1 -> RGBColor @@ ({##3}/255) &,
    Import["/path/to/AbdominalAtlas2011/AbdominalAtlasColors.ctbl", "Table"], 
    {1}];
```

Fixing the `mkGraphics` function

```
mkGraphics[file_String] := Module[
   {id = ToExpression[StringSplit[file, "_"][[2]]]}, {colors[id], 
    EdgeForm[None], Import[file, "GraphicsComplex"]}
   ];
```

And finally everything without the muscles

```
Graphics3D[
 mkGraphics /@ Select[vtks, StringFreeQ[#, "muscle"] &],
 Lighting -> "Neutral"
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: This is great. But I have a predefined set of color and opacity values. How can I apply this?